# Split a string while keeping delimiters Haskell

Tags: haskell

Basically I'm trying to split a `String` into `[[String]]` and then concat the results back but keeping the delimiters in the resultant list (even repeating in a row).

Something like the below kind of works, but the delimiter gets crunched into one space instead of retaining all three spaces

```
unwords . map (\x -> "|" ++ x ++"|") . words $ "foo   bar"
-- "|foo| |bar|"
```

Ideally I could get something like:

```
"|foo||   ||bar|" -- or
"|foo|   |bar|"
```

I just can't figure out how to preserve the delimiter, all the split functions I've seen have dropped the delimiters from the resulting lists, I can write one myself but it seems like something that would be in a standardish library and at this point I'm looking to learn more than the basics which includes getting familiar with more colloquial ways of doing things.

I think I'm looking for some function like:

```
splitWithDelim :: Char -> String -> [String]
splitWithDelim "foo   bar" -- ["foo", " ", " ", " ", "bar"]
```

or maybe it's best to use regexes here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split a list, keeping delimiters using the `keepDelimsL` and `keepDelimsR` functions in the `Data.List.Split` package, like [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html):

```
split (keepDelimsL $ oneOf "xyz") "aazbxyzcxd" == ["aa","zb","x","y","zc","xd"]
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. Somewhat dumber followup, it's noted that it's unportable and experimental, is that just out of date or overly conservative or is there a more canonical library?

Comment: @BWStearns I think the "portability" and "stability" fields are ones that frequently get set when the package is created, and then people tend to forget they're there and never update them. The `split` package is fairly weathered now; and there is definitely nothing more canonical.